# How do I get the RESTSerializer.extractArray method to work?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Copy-pasting both the "payload" and the serializer from [the API-documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractArray) I have created the folowing JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/481/

I get the following error:

> Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/UEaQ4/

Ember doesn't use normalizeHash. I don't why.
I changed payload before pass it to _super

```
payload = { 
  comments: comments.map(function(hash){
    hash.id = hash._id;
    hash.title = hash.comment_title;
    delete hash._id;
    delete hash.comment_title;
    return hash;
  }),
  posts: posts };
```

and also store comment._id in post instead of comment itself

```
postCache[comment.post_id].comments.push(comment._id);
```

and it works.